# org.datanucleus.sco.backed.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Set

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, arraylist, google-cloud-datastore

Since 4 days ago, *in random short periods of time*, my deployed application is throwing this error:

> org.datanucleus.sco.backed.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Set

We are using GWT 2.4 / Java 1.7 (We recently migrate from 1.6 to 1.7)

It happens when retrieving or persisting an entity with a String set:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
...
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class DbAccount {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
...
    @Persistent
    private Set<String> accounts;
...
    public DbAccount(SerAccount account) throws Exception {
        ...
        this.accounts= new HashSet<String>();
        ...
        key = KeyFactory.createKey(DbCuentas.class.getSimpleName(), this.id);
    }
}
```

I have checked my entire project for a reference to ***org.datanucleus.sco.backed.ArrayList*** and it does not exist.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same problem. Do you fetch these entities as part of another entity? Meaning: Does DbAccount exist inside another entity?

I'm not getting these error consistently enough to be able to debug it. They appear randomly when we have higher load on the server.

Comment: It became more and more frequent. The 'solution' (at least a 98%) was to upgrade our instances from F1 to F4.

Comment: Nice to see you get back and answer my comment (even though it's almost 2 years later ;) )! :D Weird error message for such an issue!

Answer (score 1):

It may sound stupid, but have you tried to use `List` instead of `Set` ?

After checking out the docs again, I can't find any example from Google with a `Collection` other than `List`.

Reading your issue, it looks like the JPA datanucleus impl is indeed using their own ArrayList  implementation whatever you do. I don't know why the problem happens randomly though...