# org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.simple.HashSet cannot be cast to java.util.Date

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus

From Last Few days Suddenly Our Production deployed application is throwing this error

> ***org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.simple.HashSet cannot be cast to***
>   ***java.util.Date***

We are using datanucleus-api-jpa- 3.1.3, datanucleus-api-jdo- 3.1.3 and Java 1.7

It happens when we are retrieving entry.

I have checked all the things but not getting root cause of this why this happening. I have checked this links 1) [stackoverflow-questionId-22307734](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307734/org-datanucleus-sco-backed-arraylist-cannot-be-cast-to-java-util-set) (2) [datanucleus-javadocs](http://www.datanucleus.org/javadocs/core/3.2/org/datanucleus/store/types/simple/package-summary.html) (3) [gae-jdo-docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses)

Sample Code:

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;


@PersistenceCapable
public class MyClass {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long Id;

    @Persistent
    private String domainName;

    @Persistent
    private String customerName;

    @Persistent
    private String companyName;

    @Persistent
    private Date installationDate;

    @Persistent
    private Date renewalDate;
    .....
    getter...
    setter...
}
```

Exception Message Full Stack-trace:

> **Exception message : org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.simple.HashSet**
>   **cannot be cast to java.util.Date (ErrorHandler.java:10)** 2018-02-02
>   00:15:28.671 IST com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler
>   errorHandler: Error in class DataAccessLayer (ErrorHandler.java:11)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.672 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   **com.company.projectname.dataaccesslayer.MyClass.jdoReplaceField(MyClass.java)**
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.672 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.replaceField(AbstractStateManager.java:2387)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.672 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceField(JDOStateManager.java:1877)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.672 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceField(JDOStateManager.java:1781)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.672 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.SCOUtils.createSCOWrapper(SCOUtils.java:241)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.672 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.SCOUtils.newSCOInstance(SCOUtils.java:139)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.672 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.wrapSCOField(JDOStateManager.java:2230)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.672 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.fetchFieldFromEntity(FetchFieldManager.java:468)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.673 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.fetchObjectField(FetchFieldManager.java:408)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.673 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.replacingObjectField(AbstractStateManager.java:2353)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.673 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   **com.company.projectname.dataaccesslayer.MyClass.jdoReplaceField(MyClass.java)**
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.673 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   **com.company.projectname.dataaccesslayer.MyClass.jdoReplaceFields(MyClass.java)**
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.673 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceFields(JDOStateManager.java:1935)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.673 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceFields(JDOStateManager.java:1962)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.673 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils$1.fetchFields(EntityUtils.java:974)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.673 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.loadFieldValues(JDOStateManager.java:764)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.673 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.initialiseForHollow(JDOStateManager.java:205)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.673 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerFactory.newForHollowPopulated(StateManagerFactory.java:89)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.674 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   org.datanucleus.state.ObjectProviderFactory.newForHollowPopulated(ObjectProviderFactory.java:75)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.674 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.findObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:2882)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.674 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.entityToPojo(EntityUtils.java:1014)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.674 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery$2.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:229)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.674 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery$2.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:226)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.674 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.resolveNext(LazyResult.java:96)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.674 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.resolveAll(LazyResult.java:121)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.674 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.size(LazyResult.java:115)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.674 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.StreamingQueryResult.size(StreamingQueryResult.java:151)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.675 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractQueryResult.toArray(AbstractQueryResult.java:400)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.675 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14)  java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:559)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.675 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   com.company.projectname.datastore.DataAccessLayer.searchObjects(DataAccessLayer.java:217)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.675 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   com.company.projectname.businessaccesslayer.Manager.getCustomeAppByURL(Manager.java:1475)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.675 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   com.company.projectname.sso.apps.marketplace.ServletTest.doGet(ServletTest.java:155)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.675 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
>   2018-02-02 00:15:28.675 IST
>   com.company.projectname.classnames.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
>   (ErrorHandler.java:14) 
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a data issue than code. How did you sanitize your data before saving or uploading it to your storage?

So it seems like some supposedly "Date" field in your retrieved data is not in fact a proper "Date" field. The best way would to be retrieve small amount of data at a time and then have it split out a unique identifiable field each result.

So you will see "John, David, Kate, ERROR", and you will know somewhere in your Kate entry, a Date field is not as it seems. It can be something like a encoding issue or formatting or maybe just a truncation thing. But either way, the error is with your data, not your code. Hence, this issue only happens once in a while (when it hits bad data).

Comment: I agree with you @Ying Li, What you are saying that the Error is of the data. But It really confused me Or not able to understand Because Same Entry I retrieve 5-6 time of day and the thing is this entry will update only once in a Year. So, the same entry I am able retrieve from past 5-6 month without any error AND Not able to retrieve now. And there is No DB Structure change OR code change from our side.

Comment: Also, We always retrieve data for specific customer So when we retrieve data it contains only one entry.

Comment: Not sure PersistantManager is threadsafe. Could this be a threading issue?

Comment: Based on the [link](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/jdo/pm.html) It states that "A PersistenceManagerFactory is designed to be thread-safe. A PersistenceManager is not"

Comment: If there's no data corruption or update, and you are sure the same data is being hit but it only errors "sometimes", then it could be a bug or something that GCP support can look into for you.

Could you try to pull the data in a "identifiable" way and figure out if it's the same entry causing the errors? If so, anything special about the entry itself?